# Removing all post tags except a given list

Tags: posts, tags, wp-cli

Got a request from a client to remove all post tags except the ones in a file they provided me.

Been trying to figure out how to do it with wp term, but don't see a way to work from a file.. My best guess would be something like:

```
wp term list post_tag --field=name | xargs wp term
```

That's as far as I've gotten, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks, Joe M

Comment: what's the format of that list? do you have the id for each tag or just the tag name/slug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a CSV file of your excluded ids and that this file name is `exclude_tags.csv`

the format of that file should be

```
1,2,3,4
```

This would represent tags with id `1`,`2`,`3` and `4`

try this

```
$ wp term list post_tag --exclude=$(cat exclude_tags.csv) --field=term_id | xargs wp term delete post_tag
```

Basically, this will send the output of `wp term list` to [`xargs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) which will execute the `wp term delete` command

**Get all Tags**

This will generate a file `all_tags.csv` containing all your tags, you could use it to generate your `excluded_tags.csv` file

```
wp term list post_tag --format=csv >all_tags.csv
```

*NOTE*

I was trying to do it all on command line, but for some reason I can't pass an array of term slugs to the `wp` function.  I asked over on [github](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/3360), if I get a reply I'll update it here. So the following would fetch all tags and provide a csv file containing only the tags id in `--slug=` that parameter would accept my array.

```
paste -sd, <(wp term list post_tag --field=term_id --slug=[tag1,tag2,etc]) >excluded_tags.csv
```

**UPDATE**

as it turns out, supplying multiple term slugs to `--slug=<slugs>` isn't supported as per my github [ticket](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/3360), so you would need to generate an intermediate file and manually work with that to generate your `excluded_tags.csv` file before deleting your unwanted tags.

Comment: Could I use tag names instead of ids?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I was testing with slugs, but either I have the wrong syntax or it is not supported, but I'm unable to provide a list of slugs to filter on.

Comment: okay thanks for the help, I should be able to generate a list of ids to accomplish this :)

Comment: I can provide you a way of retrieving a csv file with all `post_tags` and you could edit that output in let's say `Excel` and generate a list from that

Comment: Okay, that would be great

Comment: Updated my answer